# 'RadioButtonList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: sql, radiobuttonlist, selectedvalue

I've a RadioButtonList looks like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList 
    ID="rblAgenda" 
    SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("bitAgenda") %>'
    runat="server" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This is inside a formview which is bound to a sqlDataSource. I checked the stored procedure it is returning 1 for bitAgenda, but I'm still getting this error message:

```
'rblAgenda' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

It's driving me crazy >:( Any Idea??? Btw bitAgenda is a bit Field in database, is that what causing the problem?

Comment: are you sure the sqlDataSource is calling the sp with the correct parameters?? try displaying the value of rblAgenda to ensure it is returning the value you expect.

Comment: yes I executed the sp separately and it's returning bitAgenda=1. Is that what you meant by "displaying the value of rblAgenda"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `ListItem` values from `1` and `0` to `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: Thanks seems to be working :) I hope it's not gonna mess up my insertion now.

Comment: You could make an assumption that if the SP return null, based on your business logic it can be treated the same as a true or false.  Otherwise what you could do is instead of binding directly to the value returned you could send your value to a function that either returns a true or false or a -1

Comment: Thanks. I got a way around this problem from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5765930/713847

But yours way sounds interesting. When you said to send the value to function did you mean sth like this: 
selectedvalue = <% MyFunc(Bind("colName")) %> ??

seems like I've a lot to learn abt asp :3

Comment: Exactly you would send your data to a function that would then be responsible for handling the data as needed and returning the appropriate value.
    selectedvalue = '<%# MyFunc(Bind("colName")) %>'